# Is it possible to use T4MVC and Asynchronous operations?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, async-await, t4mvc

My Action:

```
 public virtual async Task<ActionResult> IdeaDetails(int id)
        {
```

My routes:

```
 routes.MapRoute("DesignIdeasDetails", "ideadetails/{id}",
              MVC.Designer.IdeaDetails().AddRouteValue("id", UrlParameter.Optional)
```

Error: `Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult>' to 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult'  C:\Work\luxedecorNew\Luxedecor\Luxedecor\App_Start\RouteConfig.cs   19  15  Luxedecor`

Error 2: `System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult>' does not contain a definition for 'AddRouteValue' and the best extension method overload 'System.Web.Mvc.T4Extensions.AddRouteValue(System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult, string, object)' has some invalid arguments`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The errors occur because of how async works. You need to **await** the Task in your method so that you can get the ActionResult, like this:

```
routes.MapRoute("DesignIdeasDetails", "ideadetails/{id}",
          (await MVC.Designer.IdeaDetails()).AddRouteValue("id", UrlParameter.Optional)

// or, if the method cannot be used with async/await
 routes.MapRoute("DesignIdeasDetails", "ideadetails/{id}",
          (MVC.Designer.IdeaDetails().GetAwaiter().GetResult()).AddRouteValue("id", UrlParameter.Optional)
```